# Convert a string (char) to an array (int)

Tags: c, string

i have a `file.txt` containing some int variables. I need to convert the third grup of numbers to an int `array` so I can manipulate the data the way I want:

```
EX: file.txt
============

111111 1001 20120131 30
122222 2002 20110230 25
133333 3003 20100325 12
144444 1001 20110526 18
155555 1001 20100524 25
166666 2002 20120312 30
177777 2003 20120428 28
188888 3003 20111214 15
199999 3002 20101113 27
199999 1001 20101202 29
133333 1001 20120715 25
155555 1001 20100204 24
177777 3003 20110102 30
```

I need to read the file line by line and I chose the `fscanf` function to this:

```
FILE *fp;

int n1, n2, n4;
char n3[9];
int array[9]

[...]

while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %s %d", &n1, &n2, n3, &n4);
```

Now that I have my string, how can i convert it to an int array?
I tried with:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(n3); i++)
    array[i] = atoi(strlen[i])
```

but it goes wrong... how can I resolve this?

it returns to me:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdlib.h:148:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
```

Comment: What does `strlen[i]` mean? `strlen` is a function, not an array.

Comment: strlen stays for the lenght of the string n3

Comment: It's worth noting that the "numbers" in the third column look like they're probably actually dates (formated as YYYYMMDD), not numbers.  But I suppose you can process them as ints if you want.  (E.g., processing them as ints would make sense if you just want to sort by date)

Answer (score 2):

You need something like:

```
int array[HUGE];

for (int i = 0; i < HUGE && fscanf(fp, "%d %d %s %d", &n1, &n2, n3, &n4) == 4; ++i)
{
    array[i] = atoi(n3);
}
```

The basic problem is if you don't know how many lines your file has, then you don't know how big to make your recipient array. A safer solution would be to use a dynamic array with `malloc` and `realloc`.

On that note, reading the string into a `char[9]` is alsy **very** dangerous: If the file contains the wrong data, your program dies, or worse. It would be safer all around to read the file line-by-line into a string first using `fgets`, and then tokenize and parse each line separately, e.g. using `strtoul`.

Comment: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdlib.h:148:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’

Comment: @l_core: I made some changes. The more I look at this the less I like your approach. Use `fgets` and `strtoul` instead.

Answer (score 1):

At least as I understand your question, you only really care about the numbers in the third column. Assuming that's the case, I think I'd do something more like this:

```
for (i=0; i<elements(array); i++)
    if (0 == fscanf(infile, "%*d %*d %d %*d", array+i))
        break;
```

Comment: were should i put this "for"? in or out the fscanf?

Comment: @l_core: This `for` loop includes the scanf in its body. This would read the entire file (or as many lines as you have room for in your array), putting the numbers from the third column into the array, and ignoring the other three numbers on each line.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want the third element as an integer, then why not read it in as an integer to begin with during your call to fscanf?  I.e., I think that the following will do roughly what you want:

```
#define MAX_VALUES 9

FILE *fp;

int n1, n2, n3, n4;
int array[MAX_VALUES]
int num_values;

while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4) && (num_values<MAX_VALUES))
    array[num_values++] = n3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of 8 single digits for each line then you could do something like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    array[i] = n3[i] - '0';
}
```

However, as others have said, it is not a good idea to rely on the format of the file for the length of n3[] and array[] even though I did exactly the same when replacing strlen() with 8.

I'd probably strtok() each line using space as the delimiter, then do some validation on the data to make sure it is what you think.

P.S. The third column looks like a date, are you sure you want an array of int?